# Java : convert "HelloThere" to "hello_there"

Tags: java

I want to convert all upper case in text to underscore , here are some example

```
HelloThere -> "hello_there"
ItIsExample -> "it_is_example"
```

I used this code but does not work :

```
String regex = "([A-Z][a-z]+)";
String replacement = "$1_";
str.replaceAll(regex, replacement); 
return toLowerCase(str);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `HelloThere` become `hello_there`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I used this code but does not work

Hint: Java strings are immutable.

This line:

```
  str.replaceAll(regex, replacement);
```

does not change `str`.  It returns a new string ... which you then throw on the floor.

Do this instead:

```
 return str.replaceAll(regex, replacement).toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this :

```
"HelloThere".replaceAll("(.)(\\p{Lu})", "$1_$2").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: \p{Lu}  is used to catch any uppercase letter defined by the Unicode stardard. It is a more general solution.

Comment: Found \p{Lu} here, thanks :) http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html And yes, it is more general solution.